# While command not working with delay javascript

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I am trying to make a simple cookie clicker like game so that when you click the button it starts a while loop that increments the cookie (x) plus the amount of clicker you have every second

```js
 var x = 0;
 var c = 0;

 text = document.querySelector("Header > p");
function Yeet(Add){
 x=x+Add;
 text.innerHTML = x;
}

document.querySelector("header > img").addEventListener("click",Doggo);
function Doggo (){
 Yeet(1);
}
document.querySelector("#clicker1").addEventListener("click",Clicker1);

function Clicker1 () {
 if (x > 9) {
 Yeet(-10);
 c++
 console.log(c);
 } 
}
while (c > 0) {
// statement

setInterval(Yeet(c), 1000);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <title>
  Cookie
 </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <img src="Img/cookie.png" alt="Cookie">
  <p>0</p>
  <button id="clicker1">Clicker 10 cookies 0.1cps</button>
 </header>
 <script src="Script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`while` loop is not necessary and does not await `setInterval()` call. The code at the question calls `Yeet(c)` immediately.

You can define the function that will be passed to `setInterval`, define a variable to reference `setInterval()`, call `clearInterval(reference)` if `c` is equal to `0`

```
function handleInterval() {
  if (c === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval)
  } else {
    Yeet(c)
  }
}

let interval = setInterval(handleInterval, 1000);
```